# Scope of express response

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I know this is a scope issue, but am not quite sure what I'm missing here.

I have a simple endpoint where, if a user is found I return a simple 'no user found message. Here is the function:

```
export const getOneUser = (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const foundUser = users.find((user) => user.id == id)
    checkUserExists(foundUser)
    res.send(foundUser)
}
```

I've replace my standard guard with a helper function. so instead of:

```
if(!userfound) res.send('No user was found')
```

with the following function:

```
const checkUserExists = (x) => {
    if(!x) res.send('No user found')
}
```

Since I am constantly using this guard I thought this might be a helpful function to write.

The problem is I'm getting the following error, no matter what I do, event if I import { respons } from 'express' and use that:

ReferenceError: res is not defined
at checkUserExists (file:///Users/cnak/Desktop/PROJECTS/TEST3/controllers/users.js:7:12)
at getOneUser (file:///Users/cnak/Desktop/PROJECTS/TEST3/controllers/users.js:18:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/cnak/Desktop/PROJECTS/TEST3/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/cnak/Desktop/PROJECTS/TEST3/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/cnak/Desktop/PROJECTS/TEST3/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/cnak/Desktop/PROJECTS/TEST3/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/cnak/Desktop/PROJECTS/TEST3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at param (/Users/cnak/Desktop/PROJECTS/TEST3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:360:14)
at param (/Users/cnak/Desktop/PROJECTS/TEST3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:371:14)
at Function.process_params (/Users/cnak/Desktop/PROJECTS/TEST3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:416:3)

How do I create a helper function that can actually pass a response?

I've also tried to return the 'res.send('No user found')

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not defining `res` in your `checkUserExists` function.

```
const checkUserExists = (x, res) => {
    if(!x) res.send('No user found')
}
```

and

```
...
checkUserExists(foundUser, res);
...
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are still getting error after sending **res** in **checkUserExists** method. Then problem is not here. You need to check your route, that you are passing actual **http res instance** here or not. Can you please paste your code of index.js and router file.